# Deciding if a language induced by a Presburger formula is context-free

Tags: fl.formal-languages, context-free-languages, decidability

Is the following problem decidable?

> Given $n$ and a Presburger arithmetic formula $\phi(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, determine whether the language $\{a_1^{i_1} \dots a_n^{i_n}:\phi(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n)\}$ over alphabet $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ is context-free.

For example, this covers asking if languages such as $\{a^i b^j c^{i+j}\}$, $\{a^i b^j c^i d^j\}$, $\{a^n b^n c^n\}$, $\{a^i b^j c^k: i\neq j, j \neq k, i \neq k\}$ are context-free.

Comment: This is equivalent to the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60288/status-of-an-open-problem-about-semilinear-sets ; it is however more than two-year old and asked on a different SE site.  As for the question, I believe it is still open.

Comment: @Michaël Cadilhac - thanks for the comment; I think you can change it to an answer.

Comment: I'd rather not; "still open" does not answer your question and would make the post disappear from the unanswered questions list.  Let's wait for someone having some more constructive comments than mine! :)